# Field variable not behaving as expected

Tags: c#

I am trying to add items to (**customers**) in my event handler btnClone_Click.  I am having a difficult time understanding why the Add method is not behaving correctly as the for loop is iterated - the list remains at a count of 1 and overwrites itself as the Add method is called.

If I declare a local object of my custom List (**abc**), this object behaves correctly and stores all the clones.

```
private Customer customer;
private List<Customer> customers;  

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     customer = new Customer("John", "Mendez", "jmendez@msysco.com");
     lblCustomer.Text = customer.GetDisplayText();
}
private void btnClone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<Customer> abc = new List<Customer>();         
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
          customers = new List<Customer>();
          Customer cust = (Customer)customer.Clone();
          customers.Add(cust);
          abc.Add(cust);
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, saw the mistake.  I keep re-initializing the list in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are initializing the `customers` field inside the loop

```
customers = new List<Customer>();
```

I think you should move that line to either inside the `Form1_Load` function or some other place which gets initialized only when required.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed right after I submitted the question.  This process might be my new tool for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration makes a new list and add an item in it. So it seems like you are having only last item in your list. So you have to change the `Button event` with

```
private void btnClone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<Customer> abc = new List<Customer>();
     customers = new List<Customer>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
          Customer cust = (Customer)customer.Clone();
          customers.Add(cust);
          abc.Add(cust);
     }
}
```